# How to find the equation for $m^*_p$ (the effective mass of the hole) in solid state physics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, mass, semiconductor-physics

I'm having trouble finding the $m^*_p$ equation ([effective mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(solid-state_physics)) of the hole).

I know that the equation for $m^*_n$ (effective electron mass):

[image]

Note, that following the guidance of the book, I managed to do both the exercise in the book and an activity that I am doing. I managed to find the value to approach the table (intrinsic silicon):

[image]

But when I make the values using $m^*_p$ it doesn't work, I would like to know about the $m^*_p$ equation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @LUFER: Does this help? See @ [how to find the effective mass of a hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9239/how-to-find-the-effective-mass-of-a-hole)

Comment: @LUFER: Where did you get the tables from for $m_p$ and $m_n$? Is it a web link?

Comment: This might help: [Topic 11-2: Effective Mass and Introduction to Holes](http://solidstate.mines.edu/videonotes/VN_10_2.pdf).

Comment: Please specify "doesn't work", preferentially in the form "I get XX by doing YYY, but I expected to get ZZZ because of AAA". In the current form it's not clear what you try, what values you use in which formula. It's probably easier if you write that step by step using the mathjax instead of using images.